# Editing Word Documents from Web Server

Tags: ms-word

I have looked for a solution to this but all I have found are products that are close but not what I need.

We have a program that creates a word document on the fly based on data from our database, and stores it on our server, then the user can download this file to print,email,file away.

I need something that will allow the user to open the existing document from the server, edit it, and save it back to the server.

I need this to be able to work on all browser, so activex isn't a full solution.

Comment: I've looked into this as well.  I think the closest you're going to get is Google Docs.  That's what we ended up using since it's free.  Microsoft's Office 365 is pay-per-user, and they used to have an interface in Sharepoint to be able to do this, but I'm not sure that's even an option anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser. Does Google Docs accept and use any of the macros that Word can, we used a lot of them to fill in locations on a word template? Can google store their doc on our server instead of theirs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.fabdocx.com:8086/docx4j-web-editor-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/upload.html) is a proof of concept of using CKEditor to do what you describe.

The focus is on ensuring that the "long tail" of possible docx content is preserved across the editing process.

For example, take a look at the Microsoft demo docx, which they use to compare their web apps with Google Docs, at
[google-documents-vs-word-web-app](http://www.whymicrosoft.com/Pages/google-documents-vs-word-web-app.aspx)